# Normalizing vector which causes overflow

Tags: numerical-methods, vectors

Let's say I have a vector of the form
$$[a_1e^\frac{r_1}{a_1},\hspace{2mm} a_2e^\frac{r_2}{a_2}],$$
which I can't compute because $\frac{r_i}{a_i}$ is large enough that when I raise $e$ to it, it overflows.  But suppose I actually want to normalize this vector using the 1-norm, then what I really want is
$$\frac{1}{a_1e^\frac{r_1}{a_1}+a_2e^\frac{r_2}{a_2}}[a_1e^\frac{r_1}{a_1},\hspace{2mm} a_2e^\frac{r_2}{a_2}].$$
Then this vector will of course not overflow, but the question is how to compute it.  If I take the log of the first normalized coordinate and try to simplify, and then re-exponentiate after simplification, then I have
$$\log a_1 + \frac{r_1}{a_1} - \log(a_1e^\frac{r_1}{a_1}+a_2e^\frac{r_2}{a_2}),$$
but since I can't push the log through the sum I can't really simplify this easily, what is the standard way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the log of each of the items in your original vector, then *subtract off the max* of the two logged values (so one of them becomes zero). Then exponentiate each term. Now you can normalize the vector. The result is algebraically the same as if you didn't subtract off the max, but numerically you won't have overflow.

Algebraically, if your two items are $a$ and $b$, and $m$ is their max, then
$$
{a\over a+b}={a/m \over a/m +b/m}={\exp({\log a-\log m})\over \exp({\log a-\log m}) + \exp({\log b-\log m})},
$$
and similarly for $b/(a+b)$. Note that we calculate $\log m$ as $\max(\log a, \log b)$.

Comment: this works, thanks!